polylith python dependency handling
I have been looking at the polylith python project example:
https://github.com/DavidVujic/python-polylith-example-pdm/blob/main/projects/my_fastapi_project/pyproject.toml
and am struggling to understand this section:
[tool.polylith.bricks]
"../../bases/example/greet_api" = "example/greet_api"
"../../components/example/greeting" = "example/greeting"
"../../components/example/log" = "example/log"

by including other components and bases in bricks how does the my_fastapi_project know of the dependencies of say greet_api during building the wheel. Could someone direct me to the code of the python-polylith project where this is being handled?
What I would like to know is whether it is possible to build a wheel which contains all the pyproject.toml's or a combined pyproject.toml of all the bricks and components linked to above
